# Why does my Subaru not select my paired Bluetooth phone automatically after restarting the car?

Tags: subaru, audio, bluetooth

The car is a Subaru WRX 2012 with the base radio.

It *did* reconnect automatically for the last two years until I changed phones, deleted the old phone profile, then paired the new phone. It does work correctly when phone is selected, but when I restart the car I have to *manually* select the phone's profile in the car's bluetooth menu. In the past the phone would always connect and music would play within a few seconds of restarting the car, and I didn't have to do anything manually.

I have tried other phones to troubleshoot and still have same problem: the phone will pair, and everything will work, but after restarting the car it won't switch to the phone automatically and I have to manually select the phone in the car menu.

I want the old behavior back where the car "sees" the phone and switches to it right away when I start the car, continuing a phone call in-car or play music over the speakers seamlessly.

Comment: Since the only thing that changed is the phone, is it possible the phone is the problem? Do you know that this phone should connect as the old phone did? Is it possible to add the old phone as a new phone and see if it exhibits the old or new behavior?

Comment: Old phone not available. Different (Android) phone still not  correcting issue.

Comment: See my answer below. What happened was that the dealer did the pairing when I bought the car, and I didn't see that he used the hands-free system and not the radio button controls. It's the method of pairing that creates the different behavior.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OK, a month later I figured it out!

Here's what finally worked:

1. Delete all duplicate audio devices in the Bluetooth menu
2. Pair the phone using the *hands-free system* via the steering wheel "off hook" button

This seems arbitrary but it solved my problem.
See the owner's manual page 5-38 for the exact procedure.

If you start pairing using the the radio controls you are pairing as Bluetooth Audio (page 5-33) and the car treats this differently. Puzzling.

I have the base radio so I can't speak for the up-level radio that includes navigation, but it's something to try.

Googling using different terms to reflect what I now already know I found this link which contains a lot of people with similar problems and it also explains very well:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4334614?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: thank you for taking the time to put this out here for others. i am having the same issue. my first setup the dealer did the hands free and the phone worked perfectly until i got a new phone. then the method used was thru the radio. that has failed. i will use this to fix my problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting the follow up. I'm not having this problem but I appreciate knowing there's a quick fix if this does ever happen to me.

Comment: I just did this, and it worked.  Delete any existing Bluetooth devices through the radio menu.  Press the OFF hook button on the steering wheel.  Use the radio buttons or voice control to continue.  SETUP / PHONE SETUP / PAIR PHONE / RECORD NAME.  Say the owner's name (at least 2 syllables, so you may need to say the name twice or add a last or middle name).  CONFIRM.  Go into your phone's bluetooth menu, select CAR MULTIMEDIA, and enter the passkey (1234 in my case).

Comment: You may also want to see page 310-311 here:  https://www.joomag.com/magazine/subaru-forester-manuals-2015-forester-owners-manual/0978905001394119949

Comment: 2013 Impreza with CM621UB radio here... this worked perfectly -- thanks! Curious side note is that the radio remembered a bunch of ancient long-deleted phones when working through the steering wheel interface; those phones weren't visible through the radio interface.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for this, it fixed the issue for me on a 2015 Subaru WRX. I completely forgot about the hands-free method of setting up a phone!